# iPad/iPhone issue with CSS Sprites, incorrect positioning

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad, sprite

I've run into an issue with CSS sprites used for a sidebar widget in our site. On the iPad with iOS 7.1, the sprites are all pushed down too far.

I have tried several other suggestions with no noticeable changes:

1. Specifying a background-size to prevent scaling (not a scaling issue)
2. Using `background-clip` and `-webkit-background-clip` to clip to padding box
3. Setting the viewport to `minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0`, as well as initial scale, disabling user scaling, etc.

You can see the icons on the following website:

http://eugenedining.com/featured-restaurants/

You'll notice it is only a vertical alignment issue. The icons are all in the right place horizontally. When you click on an icon, the active state (white on orange) does not shift around, althouhg it is still cut off. It is not a sizing issue.

I think the `<span>` element is actuall being pushed down by something.

Any ideas?

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I guess there is a mysterious padding / linebreak  issue of some kind that appears inside the `<a>` and before the nested `<span>` element.

Switching the span to absolute positioning  has fixed the issue, but I'm still clueless where the extra space comes from.

Luckily most of my structure is done to the `<a>` element, so this was pretty straightforward to implement.

```
.tag-list li.tag-item a {
  position: relative;
}
.tag-list li.tag-item a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```